# Night shift with css similiar to f.lux

Tags: css, reactjs, night-shift

Is it possible to create something something similar to f.lux to my website?

f.lux simulates a night shift - I would like to make my Web-App behave the same way.

So for example css property that shifts all colors to some temperature.

Right now I'm using react on the client side. Perhaps there is some plugin :) ? 
Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend on Sean's answer, you can also use `background-color` to achieve a somewhat similar effect. Also note that you would need to use `pointer-events: none` so that the orange layer doesn't prevent clicks/taps.

```css
html:before {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background-color: #ffa339;
  opacity: .1;
  pointer-events: none;
  content: ' ';
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<button>flux up!</button>
```

Disclaimer: There's probably more science behind flux/nightshift/etc., so take this with a grain of salt. Offering a dark theme might be an even better solution that helps using your site at night.

Comment: Thanks a lot something like this I was thinking of. It works very well! Only one component (that is always on top) doesn't get the color - but I think that is fine and I will find a workaround if needed!

Comment: Glad I could help. You probably need to use a higher `z-index` value!

Comment: @MichaelRazum If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yes indeed something got wrong! Your solution works very well. Misses to click

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem solved by react, *but* can be kind of solved with CSS.

```
html:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  backdrop-filter: sepia(100%);
  z-index: 10000 !important;
}
```

Caveats: Browser support for `backdrop-filter` is very scarce.

Answer (score 0):

f.lux is able to adjust the color temperature of the screen according to the position of the sun (for the current location).
If you want to achieve the same feature you have three options:

- User can toggle on/off - I would recommend this one. User has total control + easy to understand. However, it will become an annoying recurring task to adjust the screen color.
- User sets position and time of sunrise-sunrise manually - relatively challenging for the user
- Auto detection

If you want to do latter you will most certainly want to use APIs. You could get the location by IP-address (could be imprecise). Yahoo has an [API](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/) that can then show you the time of the sunrise/sunset.
This will give you the sunset Maui for example:

```
select astronomy.sunset from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text="maui, hi")
```

In order to adjust the actual brightness/color the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43769521/night-shift-with-css-similiar-to-f-lux#answer-43770089) by Fabian Schultz seems to be ideal.